# Deploy one msi to multiple sites and server

Tags: windows-installer

Just want to ask, is there away to deploy one msi installer to multiple sites and server?

Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Do you mean like, automatically? Otherwise there's no difference from deploying to just one server... then again there shouldn't be that much difference between automated deployment to one server and multiple servers.

Comment: yes, i want to automate it.. is there away to accomplish this task..

Answer (score 0):

This question is off topic for StackOverlow and should be on ServerFault.

In a nutshell, developing a package and distributing a package are two very different albeit related focus areas.   For distribution you can look at tools such as Active Directory Group Policy Software Distribution or Microsoft Systems Center Configuration Manager Software Distribution.

As a setup developer you should focus on making your MSI bulletproof and fully test the silent install/uninstall scenarios.  Beyond that it's up the customer IT organization to decide what their package delivery method will be.